# How can I check if the array of objects has duplicate property values ​and get the last value that is repeated?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to browse an array to check if the elements are repeated and then recover the last element .

```
const tabs = [
  { name: 'john', details:"john1" },
  { name: 'michael' , details:"michael1" },
  { name: 'beris' , details:"beris1" },
  { name: 'john'  , details:"john2"},
  { name: 'john'  , details:"john3"},
  { name: 'beris' , details:"beris2" },
   { name: 'beris' , details:"beris3" },
]
```

I would like to have as result

```
const tabs = [
   { name: 'john'  , details:"john3"},
    { name: 'beris' , details:"beris3" },
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: a map/dictionary would be helpful.

Comment: Why isn't `michael` in the result? because it's not repeated?

Comment: @Kaddath yes michael does not repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const tabs = [
  { name: 'john', details:"john1" },
  { name: 'michael' , details:"michael1" },
  { name: 'beris' , details:"beris1" },
  { name: 'john'  , details:"john2"},
  { name: 'john'  , details:"john3"},
  { name: 'beris' , details:"beris2" },
  { name: 'beris' , details:"beris3" },
];

// logic to create newTabs array having only latest duplicates

let names=[];
let newTabs=[];

tabs.forEach((element)=>{
 if(names.includes(element.name)){
 newTabs = newTabs.filter(function( obj ){
  return obj.name !== element.name;
  });
 newTabs.push(element);
  }else{
 names.push(element.name);
  }
});

// output newTabs array that has only latest duplicate objects!
console.log(newTabs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group objects with the same `name` into an array using a `Map`, where the key of the array is the `name` of the objects it stores. Then you can use `Array.from()` to convert the values from the map into an array, which you can then filter to only contain arrays where the occurrence is greater than one. For each array, you can then `.map()` it to get the last element:

```js
const tabs = [{ name: 'john', details:"john1" }, { name: 'michael' , details:"michael1" }, { name: 'beris' , details:"beris1" }, { name: 'john'  , details:"john2"}, { name: 'john'  , details:"john3"}, { name: 'beris' , details:"beris2" }, { name: 'beris' , details:"beris3" },];

const res = Array.from(tabs.reduce((m, o) => 
  m.set(o.name, (m.get(o.name)|| []).concat(o))
, new Map).values()).filter(({length}) => length > 1).map(vals => vals.pop());
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group your items by name and take the last element of the group if it's longer than 2.

```js
const lkp = tabs.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.name] = acc[cur.name] || [];
  acc[cur.name].push(cur); 
  return acc;
}, {});
const filtered = Object.values(lkp).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (cur.length > 1) acc.push(cur.pop());
    return acc;
}, [])
console.log (filtered)
```

```html
<script>
const tabs = [
  { name: 'john', details:"john1" },
  { name: 'michael' , details:"michael1" },
  { name: 'beris' , details:"beris1" },
  { name: 'john'  , details:"john2"},
  { name: 'john'  , details:"john3"},
  { name: 'beris' , details:"beris2" },
   { name: 'beris' , details:"beris3" },
]
</script>
```

Comment: it also works for the method but I have not yet read the reduce () method, thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following

```
var map = {}
tabs.forEach(item => map[item.name] = item)
const result = Object.values(map)
```

Comment: it returns an element that does not repeat (michael).